# C# Float does not insert as exact value

Tags: c#, sql-server

When inserting a float into a SQL Server database, I'm getting:

```
5.03000020980835
```

Which is not the exact value which is being gathered.

How I'm gathering this float? Through a text box control to be converted to float

How I'm working with the data currently:

```
   private void PayRateTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       PayRateBox = float.Parse(PayRateTextBox.Text);
   }
```

The above is setting an internal float to the current updated textbox which is set:

```
 private float PayRateBox = 0;
```

Then inserted as:

```
string Query = "INSERT INTO shifts (ShiftDate,WeekNumber,Hours,PayType,Rate) " + 
               "VALUES(@Date, @WeekNo, @Hours, @PayType, @Rate)";
```

and bound to the query via bound parameters:

```
CMD.Parameters.Add("@Rate", SqlDbType.Float);
CMD.Parameters["@Rate"].Value = PayRate;
```

The default text in the TextBox is set to 5.03, so somewhere along the lines other data is being appended to make the overall value increment. I have tried to trace where this is happening, but cannot find out how and why this is happening. Perhaps I'm overlooking something?

Comment: Floating point numbers are not exact, so this should not be surprising.

Comment: @GrantWinney After making changes to the Table and the active code. It works like a charm. New structure for the table is `decimal(3,2);` as apposed to `float`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precision of [float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) is limited to 7 significant digits. In your case it means `5.030000`. Values at the rest of decimal places are undefined.

To improve precision use either [double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) with precision of 15-16 significant digits or [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) with 28-29 significant digits.

Comment: Can accept as answer in 1 minute, though find it a little design fault if precision is lost after 7 digits

Comment: Well sometimes a precision of 7 digits is enough, depending on problem you are trying to solve. Also, `float` only has a size of 4B while `double` is 8B and `decimal` 16B. So floats will save your memory.

Comment: @DarylGill So how would you design a 32-bit floating point number that has more than 7 digits of precision?  Best you can do is 10 digits if you leave no room for an exponent (essentially an `int`)

Comment: @DarylGill It's the nature of the beast.  You trade the ability to represent a very wide range of values for an inability to accurately express any value.  When I was in college I found an entire department where none of the **teachers** understood this--nobody would believe a loop with a termination condition of x = x + 1 would ever exit.

Comment: Arbitrary precision decimal-point arithmetic is possible (based on something called p-adic arithmetic), but that's not the way modern machines implement non-integrals. Yes, it really is something lacking.